# I'm having trouble with parsing a JSON file

Tags: r, json

I am attempting to use a .json file I found online, but I'm starting to think that there is an underlying issue with the file. I am not very knowledgeable in .json files, so I am trying to convert it into a CSV file. I have yet to find a website that can do that for me.

I've tried using R to convert the file since the file is also quite large and I can only assume that most websites have a size limit. I have tried flattening it in r with this code:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)

json_string <- readLines("data.json")

json_data <- fromJSON(json_string)

json_data <- flatten(json_data)

df <- as_data_frame(json_data)

write_csv(df, "output.csv")
```

but it returns this error:

```
! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
* Size 2: Columns `A-Alrund, God of the Cosmos // A-Hakka, Whispering Raven`, `A-Blessed Hippogriff // A-Tyr's Blessing`, `A-Emerald Dragon // A-Dissonant Wave`, `A-Monster Manual // A-Zoological Study`, `A-Rowan, Scholar of Sparks // A-Will, Scholar of Frost`, and 484 more.
* Size 3: Column `Smelt // Herd // Saw`.
* Size 5: Column `Who // What // When // Where // Why`.
* Size 6: Columns `Everythingamajig`, `Garbage Elemental`, `Ineffable Blessing`, `Knight of the Kitchen Sink`, `Scavenger Hunt`, and 4 more.
i Only values of size one are recycled.
Backtrace:
 1. tibble::as_data_frame(json_data)
 3. tibble:::as_tibble.list(x, ...)
 4. tibble:::lst_to_tibble(x, .rows, .name_repair, col_lengths(x))
 5. tibble:::recycle_columns(x, .rows, lengths)
```

Here is what the first 2 items of the .json file look like

```
{"data": {"\"Ach! Hans, Run!\"": [{"colorIdentity": ["G", "R"], "colors": ["G", "R"], "convertedManaCost": 6.0, "foreignData": [], "identifiers": {"scryfallOracleId": "a2c5ee76-6084-413c-bb70-45490d818374"}, "isFunny": true, "layout": "normal", "legalities": {}, "manaCost": "{2}{R}{R}{G}{G}", "manaValue": 6.0, "name": "\"Ach! Hans, Run!\"", "printings": ["UNH"], "purchaseUrls": {"cardKingdom": "https://mtgjson.com/links/84dfefe718a51cf8", "cardKingdomFoil": "https://mtgjson.com/links/d8c9f3fc1e93c89c", "cardmarket": "https://mtgjson.com/links/b9d69f0d1a9fb80c", "tcgplayer": "https://mtgjson.com/links/c51d2b13ff76f1f0"}, "rulings": [], "subtypes": [], "supertypes": [], "text": "At the beginning of your upkeep, you may say \"Ach! Hans, run! It's the . . .\" and the name of a creature card. If you do, search your library for a card with that name, put it onto the battlefield, then shuffle. That creature gains haste. Exile it at the beginning of the next end step.", "type": "Enchantment", "types": ["Enchantment"]}], "\"Brims\" Barone, Midway Mobster": [{"colorIdentity": ["B", "W"], "colors": ["B", "W"], "convertedManaCost": 5.0, "foreignData": [], "identifiers": {"scryfallOracleId": "c64c31f2-c1be-414e-9dff-c3b77ba97545"}, "isFunny": true, "layout": "normal", "leadershipSkills": {"brawl": false, "commander": true, "oathbreaker": false}, "legalities": {}, "manaCost": "{3}{W}{B}", "manaValue": 5.0, "name": "\"Brims\" Barone, Midway Mobster", "power": "5", "printings": ["UNF"], "purchaseUrls": {"cardKingdom": "https://mtgjson.com/links/d1e320bd9d6813c0", "cardKingdomFoil": "https://mtgjson.com/links/18f86e8a04682c34", "cardmarket": "https://mtgjson.com/links/d5a3d8cfb60767d4", "tcgplayer": "https://mtgjson.com/links/980f45f2bc8c3733"}, "rulings": [], "subtypes": ["Human", "Rogue"], "supertypes": ["Legendary"], "text": "When \"Brims\" Barone, Midway Mobster enters the battlefield, put a +1/+1 counter on each other creature you control that has a hat.\n\"Brims\" Barone, Midway Mobster has menace as long as you're wearing a hat.", "toughness": "4", "type": "Legendary Creature — Human Rogue", "types": ["Creature"]}]}
```

I am hoping that the resulting csv file has the keys as the column names, and the values to be assigned to the columns based on their keys.

EDIT:
I have now attached a screenshot of what the json_data structure looks like.[Structure of json_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ3v3.png)

Comment: This looks like a database of Magic: The Gathering cards from Scryfall.  What does the structure of the `json_data` object in your workflow look like?

Comment: It looks like the problematic rows are for flip cards and fuse cards - those with multiple names.  The structure of the `json_data` object will help address that.

Comment: also note that both jsnolite and purrr (part of tidyverse) have functions called `flatten()` - it might be best to explicitly call the one you need e.g. `jsonlite::flatten()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's one of the JSON dumps from scryfall, try this:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)

todo <- list.files(pattern = ".json")
json_data <- fromJSON(todo)

json_data_flat_jsl <- jsonlite::flatten(json_data)

df <- as_tibble(json_data_flat_jsl)

write_csv(df, "output.csv")
```

Comment: One thing I do know sometimes would give me an error when I was parsing it, was that there are a whole bunch of languages in the file. The code now returns this error:

Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       NA
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: Also, if I only modify my code to specify that I want to use the jsonlite::flatten, it returns the error:
Error in jsonlite::flatten(json_data) : is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE